# CakePHP 2.2.0 - AuthComponent - different Model than User - password always incorrect

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a problem with logging in on a different Model than User with AuthController.

It's administrators, not users table.

In my Administrator Model I have:

```
function beforeSave(){
        if(isset($this->data['Administrator']['password'])) 
            $this->data['Administrator']['password'] = AuthController::password($this->data['Administrator']['password']); 
            return true; 
    }
```

AppController:

```
public $components = array(
        'Session', 
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'Home', 'action' => 'index'), 
            'authError' => "You can't access that page.",
            'authorize' => array('Controller')      
        )
    );


    public function beforeFilter(){
        $this->Auth->userModel = 'Administrator';
    }
```

In AdministratorController:

```
    public function login(){
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                if($this->Auth->login()){
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
                }
                else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect.');
                }
            }
        }

public function logout(){
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

And view:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Administrator', array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('username');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Form->end('Login');
?>
```

I debugged $this->request->data['Administrator']['password'] and I've got the same hash like in the database.

I don't know why it always says that the username/password is incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure it is not hashing it twice before saving? And is it hashing the login field for the right comparison?

Comment: Checked. :) It's not that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `AuthComponent::password`, not `AuthController::password`.

Comment: Changed. Still not that. :) Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by including the following code in your AppController.

```
public $components = array(
'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'Administrator',
                'fields' => array(
                    'username' => 'USER_LOGINNAME',
                    'password' => 'USER_PASSWORD'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

In AppController beforeFilter() method write the following:

```
 public function beforeFilter()
{        
    if($this->Auth->user('USER_ID'))
    {
        $this->set('logged_in', true);                     
    }
    else
    { 
        $this->set('logged_in', false);
    }

    //Configure AuthComponent
    $this->Auth->userScope = array('Administrator.USER_STATUS' => '1');
    $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login');
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'dashboard');        
}
```

In your Administrator Model:

```
public function beforeSave()
{
    if(!empty($this->data['Administrator']['USER_PASSWORD']))
    {
        $this->data['Administrator']['USER_PASSWORD'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['Administrator']['USER_PASSWORD']);    
    }        
    return true;
}
```

And in your administrators controller:

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('login');
}
```

Comment: Do I have to put something for the USER_LOGINNAME, like $this->request->data['Administrator']['username']?

Comment: USER_LOGINNAME AND USER_PASSWORD are the custom fields if even your administrators table does not contain username and password as the default fields.

Comment: Oh... It's username and password in Administrators table. I understand. Thank you. I'll try it now.

Comment: I did it. Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! I just wanna hug you now!!! Hahaha xD.

Comment: If it worked for you, then you should marked it as answer and also vote me up.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public function login(){
            if($this->request->is('post')){
                if($this->Auth->login()){

// dont use this line /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
use this
'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'administrators', 'action' => 'login'),
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////                
 }
                else{
                    $this->Session->setFlash('Your username/password combination was incorrect.');
                }
            }
        }

public function logout(){
        $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}

public function beforeFilter(){
        parent::beforeFilter();
}
```

Comment: You should explain the solution you're posting in more detail.